# how can I get category using summary()

Tags: r, summary

When I get a summary in R, I get this instead of a list of the items. In this case, it should be HIGH/LOW/NORMAL, but I get length/ class/mode instead. is any setting off in my R? Please advise if you happen to know.

[image]

Comment: Use `as.factor()` on the `group` variable before using `summary()`.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg